# Why not conflating a distribution over distributions with a distribution?

Tags: distributions, philosophical

This question is more like a philosophical one. I constantly find the notion of *a distribution over distributions* and redundant. Why don't we conflate that with the notion of *a single distribution* (by integration)?

For example, suppose our parameter space is the closed interval $\Theta = [0,1]$. A point $\theta \in \Theta$ specifies a distribution, say the pdf $b_\theta$ of $Bern(\theta)$. Such distribution encodes our best guess of the state. However, in some contexts, people consider distributions $f(\theta)$ over $\Theta$. **Effectively speaking**, the distribution over the distributions $f(\theta)$ should no difference from the effective pdf $$\int f(\theta) \cdot b_\theta \,d\theta.$$ **After all, isn't all we care about the effective pdf?**

The only flaw I could find in my argument is the choice of the measure on $\Theta$. Could that be the main reason why people don't conflate these two notions?

#### TLDR

Given a measure $\mu$ on the parameter space $\Theta$, integration induces a natural map $\hat{\mu}: Dist(\Theta) \to \Theta$. I think the points in the domain of $\hat{\mu}$ should be considered the same if their images agree. Why do people pretend that they aren't the same?

Comment: Conditioning (in your example on $\theta$) can be helpful in constructing models ...

Comment: I think you meant to write $\hat\mu: Dist(\Theta) \mapsto \{b_\theta: \theta \in \Theta\}$, as the integral is definitely not a number.

Comment: It would help to have some context here.  You are obviously losing information in your simplification, which suggests what where people are formulating distributions over spaces of distributions, they have a reason to do so.

Comment: @LukasLohse that's right, but it's a bijection so I think it's ok to do that.

Comment: @whuber I know, but that's the point. I think we'd like to think that we gain more information by considering something in $Dist(\Theta)$ instead of $\Theta$, but do we really?

Answer (score 2):

I think there are a lot of things to touch on here. To start with, obviously this framework mostly comes up in Bayesian statistics, where $f(\theta)$ is the prior/posterior and $p_f(x) := \int_\Theta f(\theta)b_\theta(x) d\theta$ would be prior/posterior predictive distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution).

Now the important thing to know is that the Bernoulli distributions are a very special case and in general $
p_f \not\in \{b_\theta: \theta \in \Theta\}!$ For example if you take the classic set up of $\Theta$ being binomial distributions and $f$ being a beta-distribution, then $p_f$ will be a beta-binomial distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution). Very much not the same thing! There are a few more exceptions, especially with normal distributions, but generally speaking the normally used parameter/distribution spaces are not closed under this conflating and therefore your mapping does not exist.

In closing the "statistics part" of Bayes we change $f$, but $\Theta$ stays the same, so why conflate them? It's just unnecessary complexity. Afterwards, if we want to bet on the super bowl or something, we do put them together. If two different priors/posteriors truly produce identical predictions over all possible scenarios, then I would call them equivalent, but this would mostly imply that $\Theta$ was unnecessarily complex to begin with.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed as you pointed out $\Theta$ isn't closed. I really came from a nonparametric point of view so I missed that. And thanks for pointing out the term "predictive distribution" to me. My question could have been posed simply as "Why don't we conflate a prior/posterior with its predictive distribution?" In your setting where $\Theta$ is simple, I get your point now. But I think in the nonparametric setting, where $\Theta$ is very large and therefore close, there should be no difference between the two notions.

Comment: Maybe, it's hard to say what $\Theta$ is in that context. However after i wrote my answer i noticed that to $f$s with identical predictive distribution can evolve differently under Bayesian updates. For example Bernoulli distributions, with $f_1$ the flat prior $U([0,1])$ and $f_2$ a symmetric but not flat distribution like $U([0, 0.1] \cup [0.9, 1])$ will have initially identical, but after observing (1, 0, 1) predict very differently.

Comment: Yeah, so they are equivalent in the sense of predicting, but inequivalent in our imaginations..